# How to find Integration of Trigonometric function with this rules $R(-\sin x,-\cos x)=R(\sin x,\cos x).$..

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\int \dfrac{dx}{1+\sin^2 x}$$
If this formula is true, $R(- \sin x,-\cos x)=R(\sin x,\cos x)$, this thing can be used $t=tgx$, $\sin x=\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$, $\cos x=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$, $dx=\dfrac{dt}{t^2+1}$, so we apply this rules if the formula is true. I don't know how this work and there are 2-3 more like this. If anyone can explain how this formulas need be used it will be very helpful for me. :)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Substitute $$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$ and $$dx=\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$ so our integral is given by $$\int\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)^2}dt$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\int\dfrac{a\sin^2x+b\sin x\cos x+c\cos^2x}{p\sin^2x+q\sin x\cos x+r\cos^2x}dx$$

Divide numerator & denominator by $\cos^2x$ and choose $\tan x=t$